# React abstract component (ES6) that renders an array of components. How to create a d.ts file for it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, .d.ts

I am trying to create a declaration file for the next component. It was written with JS ES6.

```
function Column({ className, layout }) {
    function renderLayout() {
        return layout.map((item, index) => {
            const Component = item?.component || item;

            return (
                <Component
                    {...item?.options}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                    key={index}
                />
            );
        });
    }

    return (
        <div className={className} >
            {renderLayout()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Example of declaration:

```
<Column
    className='test'
    layout={[
        {
            component: Input, // It can use options
            options: {  // It can have a custom shape. How to define types for options?
                first: 'test' 
            }
        },
        {
            component: Date, // It can use options
            options: { // It can have a custom shape. How to define types for options?
                second: 'test', 
                newValue: { index: 3 } 
            }
        }
    ]}
/>
<Column
    className='test'
    layout={[Input, Date]}
/>
```

I have a problem with **options** property. I do not know how to define types for the object as it can have different types depending on the **component** the user pass with.

**Input**, **Date** - are examples of components, it can be replaced with any other components.

My declaration file.

```
interface ILayout {
    component?: React.ElementType;
    options?: any; // <---- Here is a problem. How to replace any with defined types.
}

interface ColumnProps {
    className?: string;
    layout?: (ILayout|React.ElementType)[];
}

export class Column extends React.Component<ColumnProps> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `ILayout` a conditional type:

```js
type ILayout = {
    component?: InputType;
    options?: OptionsForInputType
} | {
    component?: DateType;
    options?: OptionsForDateType
}
```